# Iron Man further movie plans

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

Marvel Entertainment has released three blockbuster movies in the *Iron Man* franchise so far.

Has there been any **official comment** from Marvel Studios and/or the producers on whether there will be any more entries in the *Iron Man* franchise?

Official sources only please.  I am not looking for opinions or gossip sites.

Comment: I know that i can search this on internet. But i want inputs from different people and i guess this is the best place for that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking here but if you don't make note of any work on your part (e.g."I found this article on ____ and this one on ___ but they don't have direct sources, is there any other info directly from the studio or producers") you can't fault us for down voting you... show us you've done **some** work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of writing this answer there has not been anything official in regards to confirming future Iron Man franchise movies being greenlight.  However, Marvel Studios head Kevin Feige has touched on the subject of new actors / recasting roles, etc.

> We have a new Spider-Man right now who was in our “Civil War” film and is in “Spider-Man: Homecoming,” and the audience has embraced it. And you can look to Sherlock Holmes, James Bond, and Batman as characters that last longer than any one actor playing them. There’s a precedent for it in other franchises that suggests it’s possible. But right now I don’t want to think about it and don’t need to think about it."
>
> <sup>[Variety via Comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2016/11/22/marvel-phase-4-recasting-actors-characters-contracts/#)</sup>

---

> "Well, if I believe Tony Stark to be James Bond, then there would be an Iron Man 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9...". But without Robert Downey Jr? "That's the question. That's a question we won't have to face until after Avengers 3, so that's at least five or six years away".
>
> <sup>[Den of Geek.com](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/marvel/27910/kevin-feige-on-ultron-spider-man-edward-norton-iron-man-4)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In a recent interview, the writers of *Avengers: Endgame* said they didn't know of plans for further "Iron Character" movies. That doesn't mean there won't *ever* be one (there likely will, as there's money to be made), but given that Markus and McFreely are now pillars of the MCU, they might have been told if there already was.

> **Fandango: Iron Man is dead, but do you feel like there is a world where an Iron Character will live on and take up that mantle? Is it Pepper?**
>
> **Christopher Markus:** Ooh, well there certainly are a bunch of people with suits who are alive.
>
> **Stephen McFeely:** But we don't know what they've got planned.
>
> **Christopher Markus:** Yeah, there are no *Iron Teen* scripts as far as I know.
>
> <sub>[*The 'Avengers Endgame' Writers Break Down The Biggest Moments in The Movie*, Erik Davis for *Fandango*, May 3rd, 2019](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-the-avengers-endgame-writers-break-down-the-biggest-moments-in-the-movie-spoilers-753736)</sub>